# Model Form not displaying

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I created a model form but it's not showing in the page but it's registered on the django admin site.[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjSMo.png)[[forms.py
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3qud.png)models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6LHu.png)
[the error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxlv3.png)

I tried creating the models using django shell

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.contrib import messages 
from .forms import AttendeeForm 

# Create your views here. 

def attendees_reg(request): 
    form = AttendeeForm() 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = AttendeeForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            messages.success(request, 'Data Has been Saved') 
            return redirect('/attendees') 

    return render(request, "templates/attendees_reg.html", {'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm 
from .models import Attendee 

class AttendeeForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Attendee 
        fields = "all"
```

**template**

```
</h1> <hr> 

{% for message in messages %} 
<p>{{message}}</p> 
{% endfor %} 

<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %} 
{{ form.as_p }} 
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: You should paste *code*, **not** [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).  Second it should be `if request,method == 'POST'` with POST in capitals.  Finally, I don't see your **forms.py** and I would need to see your template to find the error.

Comment: here's my template code

<h1>Attendee Form</h1>

<hr>

{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
{% endfor %}
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: I still need to see your **forms.py** file where you have the `AttendeeForm` form located.  Also you have a line in your **views.py** that says `from .form import AttendeeForm`.  The file is usually called *forms.py* not form.py.  I do not know if that matters.  So far, other than the errors I have already mentioned, I do not see why your form is not working.

Comment: forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm 
from .models import Attendee

class AttendeeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendee
        fields = "__all__"

Comment: views.py 


from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import AttendeeForm
# Create your views here.


def attendees_reg(request):
    form = AttendeeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AttendeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Data Has been Saved')
            return redirect('/attendees')
        
    
    return render(request, "templates/attendees_reg.html", {'form':form})

Comment: Okay, in addition to the errors already stated, there is another in your **forms.py**.  Where you have `fields = "all"`, it should be `fields = '__all__'`.

Comment: To write code in your answer you can just edit your answer instead of putting code into the comments.  To do this it's simple.  One way is to just paste it in, then select the text you want formatted as code, then hit the `{}` as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqwk.png)

Comment: I still keep getting the page header and the submit button... no form is being displayed

Comment: Is the template you gave me the one for `templates/attendees_reg.html`?  I see the path in your photo as `127.0.0.1:8000/attendees`, but the form is being sent to the template `templates/attendees_reg.html`.  I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas.  Maybe add your **urls.py**.

Comment: You're welcome!  Was that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be correct `"__all__"` instead of `"all"`

```
class AttendeeForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Attendee 
        fields = "__all__"
```